# Include Velocity Template In Another In Spring App

Tags: java, spring, templates, velocity

I may be trying to do something a bit out of the ordinary.  I have a spring web application, and I am rendering a velocity template manually, meaning calling

```
template.merge(context, stringWriter)
```

Here is how I am getting the template from the application:

```
InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/vml/" + templateName);
String templateString = StreamUtils.inputStreamToString(inputStream);
RuntimeServices runtimeServices = RuntimeSingleton.getRuntimeServices();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(templateString);
SimpleNode node = runtimeServices.parse(reader, templateName);
Template template = new Template();
template.setRuntimeServices(runtimeServices);
template.setData(node);
template.initDocument();
```

I believe I have to load the template this way because I am not using Spring's `VelocityViewResolver` to render the template as part of a request (this is part of a background task in Jboss).  But now I am of course unable to include templates in this template, because Velocity doesn't know where to get them, and I have not set `TEMPLATE_ROOT` and I am not using the Velocity ClasspathResourceLoader either.

So my question is, what are my options here?  The basic goal is to be able to manually render these templates, and be able to include one template in another, all within a Spring web app.

I have tried using the ClasspathResourceLoader via

```
static {
    velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
    velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
    velocityEngine.init();
}
```

and I placed a small hello world template under `WEB-INF/vml/hello.vml`.  When I attempt to call `velocityEngine.getTemplate("/vml/hello.vml");` both with and without a leading forward slash before the vml, I get a `org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource '/vml/hello.vml'`.  I am stuck here as this exhausts both methods I know of to get the template.

Comment: As your templates are not in classpath but directly under WEB-INF (which is normal for a web application), you cannot use `ClasspathResourceLoader`.

Comment: So what are my options?

Comment: In other words, without any of the velocity initialized loaders, how do I include one template in another?  or must I use either the classloader or the url loader?

Comment: I think it is possible through velocity initialization. How do you initialize your `VelocityEngine` ? Is it a Spring bean ? Or are you using the *velocity singleton model* only using `Velocity` class ?

Comment: It is not currently a Spring bean, though I am not averse to trying that method.  Currently it is initialized as above, with `    private static VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();

    static {
        velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        velocityEngine.init();
    }`

Comment: Does that qualify as the latter option `Or are you using the velocity singleton model only using Velocity class`?

Comment: No, you are using a VelocityEngine. I allready did things not far away from want you need but have currently no access to my sources. I should be able to propose a solution tomorrow, but I still have one question : do you have any constraints on version of Velocity and Velocity tools ? If I correctly remember I last used velocity 1.7 and velocity tools 2.0.

Comment: That would be great.  I can use any version, velocity 1.7 and velocity tool 2.0 would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity configuration is not the best documented part in Spring. And it is rather outdated : even in 4.0.5, the reference documentation declares dependencies on velocity 1.x (fine) and velocity-tools (1.x) which is deprecated in recent versions of velocity. Nevertheless all works fine once configured with velocity 1.7 and velocity-tools 2.0

The piece that will allow velocity to find your templates under WEB-INF is `WebappResourceLoader` of velocity-tools. Once your `VelocityEngine` will be declared to use it to load templates, all will work fine, including template inclusion in other templates.

So you can keep doing the configuration *the velocity way*. You prepare the velocity properties including :

```
resource.loader=webapp
webapp.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader
webapp.resource.loader.path=/WEB-INF/vml
```

and initialize and use normally a `VelocityEngine`

But you can also make use of Spring `VelocityConfigurer`, which could be useful if you later want to use velocity views in your application (*). Here is an extract of a working application context :

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/"/>
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="input.encoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="output.encoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="velocimacro.library">VM_global_library.vm</prop>
            <prop key="resource.loader">webapp</prop>
            <prop key="webapp.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader</prop>
            <prop key="webapp.resource.loader.path">/WEB-INF/vlm</prop>
            <prop key="evaluate.provide.scope.control">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="velocityEngine" factory-bean="velocityConfig" factory-method="getVelocityEngine"/>
```

And you get a fully configured `VelocityEngine` that can be injected by Spring in any bean where you need it (I think that `property name="resourceLoaderPath"` is a scory of on older version, but as it works I didn't dare remove it, and `VM_global_library.vm` is my own velocity macro library under `webapp.resource.loader.path`, accessible from all my templates). I currently use this config to generate mail bodies.

No that you have your velocity engine (configured either directly or via a `VelocityConfigurer`) you use it to load and merge your templates :

```
Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("/hello.vml");
Context context = new VelocityContext();
context.put(..., ...);
...
template.merge(context, writer);
```

(*) `VelocityLayoutViewResolver` works correctly in that environment, but to be able to use a 2.0 velocity toolbox, I had to modify the default Spring `VelocityLayoutView` and declare my subclass in resolver :

in dispatcher-servlet :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver"
      id="vmViewResolver" p:order="10" p:suffix=".vm" p:prefix=""
      p:cache="true" p:contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"
      p:exposeRequestAttributes="false" p:exposeSessionAttributes="false"
      p:exposePathVariables="true" p:exposeSpringMacroHelpers="true"
      p:dateToolAttribute="date" p:toolboxConfigLocation="/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml"
      p:viewClass="i2.application.commun.web.views.Velocity2LayoutView">
...
```

and my `Velocity2LayoutView`

```
public class Velocity2LayoutView extends VelocityLayoutView {
    ViewToolManager toolManager;

    @Override
    protected Context createVelocityContext(Map<String, Object> model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ViewToolContext context = toolManager.createContext(request, response);
        context.putAll(model);
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initTool(Object tool, Context velocityContext) throws Exception {
        //super.initTool(tool, velocityContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        toolManager = new ViewToolManager(getServletContext(), false, false);
        if (getToolboxConfigLocation() != null) {
            String path = getToolboxConfigLocation();
            logger.debug("Init ViewToolManager with " + path);
            XmlFactoryConfiguration config = new XmlFactoryConfiguration();
            config.read(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(getToolboxConfigLocation()));
            toolManager.configure(config);
        }
        toolManager.setVelocityEngine(getVelocityEngine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, by the power of Greyskull!  That'll do it!  Thank you sir.

Comment: Quick follow up, now I notice that $contextVariable are not being interpreted in included templates, but are coming out as the literal string '$contextVariable'.  Is the context not available in these included templates?  How do I make it so?

Comment: Also my foreach loops etc are being rendered literally, for example `#foreach($foo in $fooList) ... #end` is coming out literally as such.  What should I do?

Comment: It appears that the velocityEngine is not recognizing these includes as velocity templates.  Maybe I need to configure it as such..

Comment: @DavidWilliams : in velocity,  `#include` is only to include fix text. You have to use `#parse` to include another template.

Comment: Of course, doh!  http://www.blacksheepfitnessacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Homer-Simpson-Doh.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Following javadoc of [ClasspathResourceLoader](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html)
Try putting your templates into WEB-INF/lib directory. For testing purposes, try to not create any subdirectories like vml, so you won't get confused when something still won't work.

Comment: I think one of the tricky things here is that the WEB-INF is exploded and deployed to a custom location `/usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/myServlet/deploy/dev.ear/dev.war/WEB-INF/lib/hello.vml`  I still get the `org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource '/hello.vml'`  When I print the classpath to the logger via `URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            LOGGER.info("Classpath item: " + url.getFile());
        }`, I see `Classpath item: /usr/share/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.jar`